# Problem with Array Formula and Concatenate

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to build an array formula on google sheets for this :

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(C2,4,3),(MID(C2,1,3)),MID(C2,7,4))
```

The problem is that when I use array formula going from `C2:C`, it will concatenate all the rows at the same time, which is not what I want.

Does anybody know how to properly use the array on that case? So it will keep looking for just the value on `C2`, `C3`,`C4` and so on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ampersand character instead of CONCATENATE:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C="", "", MID(C2:C,4,3)&(MID(C2:C,1,3))&MID(C2:C,7,4)))
```

Comment: You're amazing Erik! Thank you so much! It worked fine!

Comment: Happy to help, Antonio. If you would, please take a moment to mark the answer "Best Answer." I don't get any prizes. It just helps other contributors here to know that the issue has been solved; and it helps future people who may search to more quickly find solutions to their similar issues. Thanks.